# Clase DATE mostrar en main

Tags: java

He creado un programa que guarda una fecha por defecto y he añadido un método para para incrementar el día (+1) a la fecha actual y otro para
incrementar el mes.

**No se como mostrar por pantalla el método incrementarMes y incrementarDia en el main**

```
public class MiFecha {

private String dia;
private String mes;
private String anyo;
private String hora;
private String minuto;

public MiFecha(String dia, String mes, String anyo, String hora, String minuto) {
    this.dia = dia;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.hora = hora;
    this.minuto = minuto;
}

public Date incrementarDia(Date fecha, int dias) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime(fecha);

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dias);

    return calendar.getTime();

}

public Date incrementarMes(Date mes, int dias) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime(mes);

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dias);

    return calendar.getTime();

}

public String getDia() {
    return dia;
}

public void setDia(String dia) {
    this.dia = dia;
}

public String getMes() {
    return mes;
}

public void setMes(String mes) {
    this.mes = mes;
}

public String getAnyo() {
    return anyo;
}

public void setAnyo(String anyo) {
    this.anyo = anyo;
}

public String getHora() {
    return hora;
}

public void setHora(String hora) {
    this.hora = hora;
}

public String getMinuto() {
    return minuto;
}

public void setMinuto(String minuto) {
    this.minuto = minuto;
}

public String toString(String Fecha) {
    return dia + mes + anyo + hora + minuto;

}
}
```

y el main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    MiFecha fecha = new MiFecha("lunes ", " enero ", "2017 ", "hora: 19 : ", "minutos: 45 ");
    System.out.print(fecha.getDia());
    System.out.print(fecha.getMes());
    System.out.print(fecha.getAnyo());
    System.out.print(fecha.getHora());
    System.out.println(fecha.getMinuto());
    System.out.println("*****************************************");
    System.out.println("Introduce una nueva fecha al sistema para incrementar fecha : ");
    String Modificarfecha = teclado.next();
    System.out.println("La fecha ha sido modificada: " + incrementarDia);
    System.out.println("*****************************************");

    System.out.println("Introduce una nueva hora:  ");
    String ModificarHora = teclado.next();
    System.out.println("La hora ha sido modificada:" + ModificarHora);




}
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mejorar la redacción de tu pregunta? No se entiende muy bien.

Comment: @gibranalexismorenozuñiga Ya esta, el problema lo tengo con los dos métodos que tengo en la clase MiFecha. Gracias

Comment: @bpico no entiendo **No se como mostrar por pantalla el método incrementarMes y incrementarDia en el main** quieres mostrar el nombre de esas funciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega un `private Date fecha` en el constructor inicializalo con los parametros de su constructor en el constructor de tu clase.

`Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min)`

Crea su getter.

Agrega un método que convierta el date en string

```
 public static String getFechaString(Date fecha) {
    SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return formateador.format(fecha);
}
```

Hasta al último solo pásale los parámetros a tus métodos

```
System.out.println("el dia modificado es: " + fecha.getFechaString(incrementarDia(fecha.getFecha(), dia));
```

Tu codigo quedaría así:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MiFecha {
    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int anyo;
    private int hora;
    private int minuto;
    private Calendar fecha;

```
public MiFecha(int dia, int mes, int anyo, int hora, int minuto) {
    this.dia = dia;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.hora = hora;
    this.minuto = minuto;
    this.fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.fecha.set(anyo, mes, dia, hora, minuto);
}

public Date incrementarDia(Calendar fecha, int dias) {
    this.fecha = fecha;

    fecha.add(Calendar.DATE, dias);

    return fecha.getTime();

}

public Date incrementarMes(Calendar fecha, int dias) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
    fecha.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dias);

    return fecha.getTime();

}

public int getDia() {
    return dia;
}

public void setDia(int dia) {
    this.dia = dia;
}

public int getMes() {
    return mes;
}

public void setMes(int mes) {
    this.mes = mes;
}

public int getAnyo() {
    return anyo;
}

public void setAnyo(int anyo) {
    this.anyo = anyo;
}

public int getHora() {
    return hora;
}

public void setHora(int hora) {
    this.hora = hora;
}

public int getMinuto() {
    return minuto;
}

public void setMinuto(int minuto) {
    this.minuto = minuto;
}

public Calendar getFecha() {
    return this.fecha;
}

public int toString(int Fecha) {
    return dia + mes + anyo + hora + minuto;
}

public static String getFechaString(Date fecha) {
    SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return formateador.format(fecha);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    Lenguaje fecha = new Lenguaje(3, 1, 2017, 19, 45);
    System.out.println(fecha.getFechaString(fecha.getFecha().getTime()));
    System.out.println("*****************************************");
    System.out
            .println("Introduce una nueva fecha al sistema para incrementar fecha : ");
    int incrementarDia = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("el dia modificado es "
            + fecha.getFechaString(fecha.incrementarDia(fecha.getFecha(),
                    incrementarDia)));
    System.out.println("*****************************************");
}
```

}

Comment: esta muy bien la solución. Lo único es que da error NullPointerException . Mirare a ver de donde viene.

Comment: Ya lo he modificado y funciona correctamente, se me habían pasado unas cosas pero no tenía editor a la mano para verificarlo

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu función "incrementarDia()" te solicita dos parametros, un objeto de tipo Date y un entero, tú lo estás tratando de imprimir de la siguiente manera :

```
System.out.println("La fecha ha sido modificada: " + incrementarDia);
```

Cuando deberias de mandarle algo como lo siguiente :

```
System.out.println("La fecha ha sido modificada: " + fecha.incrementarDia(new Date(), 1));
```

Sin embargo lo que tu quieres es que te imprima la fecha que tienes guardada en tu mismo objeto más la cantidad de días, por lo cual debes hacer dos cosas, crear una función getFecha() en tu objeto MiFecha y pedir un entero en tu Scanner() por lo cual quedaría así:

```
public class MiFecha {

private String dia;
private String mes;
private String anyo;
private String hora;
private String minuto;
//Creamos un objeto de tipo fecha
private Date fecha;

public MiFecha(String dia, String mes, String anyo, String hora, String minuto) {
    this.dia = dia;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.hora = hora;
    this.minuto = minuto;
}

//Constructor para inicializar la fecha

 public MiFecha(int dia, int mes, int anyo, int hora, int minuto) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Asignamos la fecha con ayuda del objeto Calendar
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, dia);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mes);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, anyo);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hora);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
    fecha = calendar.getTime();
}

public Date incrementarDia(Date fecha, int dias) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime(fecha);

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dias);

    return calendar.getTime();

}

public Date incrementarMes(Date mes, int dias) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime(mes);

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dias);

    return calendar.getTime();

}

public String getDia() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fecha);
    return String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

public void setDia(String dia) {
    this.dia = dia;
}

public String getMes() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fecha);
    return String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
}

public void setMes(String mes) {
    this.mes = mes;
}

public String getAnyo() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fecha);
    return String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}

public void setAnyo(String anyo) {
    this.anyo = anyo;
}

public String getHora() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fecha);
    return String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
}

public void setHora(String hora) {
    this.hora = hora;
}

public String getMinuto() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fecha);
    return String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}

public void setMinuto(String minuto) {
    this.minuto = minuto;
}

public String toString(String Fecha) {
    return dia + mes + anyo + hora + minuto;

}

//Encapsulamos la fecha

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

  }
```

El main:

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Inicializamos la fecha con el nuevo constructor, colocaré aquí la misma fecha que usaste pero con su nuevo equivalente
    MiFecha fecha = new MiFecha(23, 0, 2017, 19, 45);
    System.out.print(fecha.getDia());
    System.out.print(fecha.getMes());
    System.out.print(fecha.getAnyo());
    System.out.print(fecha.getHora());
    System.out.println(fecha.getMinuto());
    System.out.println("*****************************************");
    System.out.println("Introduce una nuevo día del mes : ");
    //Aquí pediremos los días que se quieran incrementar
    int modificarfecha = teclado.nextInt();

    //Esto para imprimir fecha en español
    SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy 'a las ' HH':'MM", new Locale("es_ES"));
    Date fechaDate = new Date();

    //A tu función le mandamos su propia fecha y los días que queramos incrementar
    System.out.println("La fecha ha sido modificada: " + formateador.format(fecha.incrementarDia(fecha.getFecha(), modificarfecha)));
    System.out.println("*****************************************");

    System.out.println("Introduce una nueva mes:  ");
    modificarfecha = teclado.nextInt();
    //A tu función le mandamos su propia fecha y los meses que queramos incrementar
    System.out.println("La hora ha sido modificada:" + formateador.format(fecha.incrementarMes(fecha.getFecha(), modificarfecha)));

}

}
```